# Angular 2 app not working in production Mode

Tags: angular, angular-cli

i'm new in angular 2 , i create my first app with three components and it works fine in NodeJs. i generate the dist folder using ng build in order to run my app out of nodeJs , i moved all the js files(main.bundle,vendor.bundle..) to a new folder called angular2-test, but when i call angular2-test/index.html the app not working and i get the following error in the web browser  console :

```
GET file:///C:/inline.bundle.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND        index.html:14
GET file:///C:/polyfills.bundle.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND     index.html:15
GET file:///C:/styles.bundle.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND        index.html:16
GET file:///C:/vendor.bundle.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND        index.html:17
GET file:///C:/main.bundle.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND          index.html:18
GET file:///C:/favicon.ico net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

this is my index.html code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bangular</title>
  <base href="/angular2-test">


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

also i changed my `<base href` to :

```
<base href="/"> and <base href="./">
```

but the app still not working,
please do you have any suggestion about my problem , note that i'm using Angular cli

Regards.

Comment: What server are you using the serve the files in the `angular2-test` directory?

Comment: Hi, i'm using apache , i put the folder angular2-test in htdocs folder and i run xampp this is the full url : http://localhost/angular2-test/

Comment: Did you actually upload the files?..

Comment: no , im testing the app locally in my machine using xampp

Comment: The js files have to be in the same directory as the index.html. The question makes me think you have moved just the js files to a sub directory without changing the src path in the index.html.

Comment: Hi Richard, all the js files are in the same directory ,this is the folder structure : https://ibb.co/nO5yCa

Comment: Actually, try changing the base href to `<base href=".">`, Does that help at all?

Comment: yes finally it works (y), but my routes not works , like http://localhost/angular2-test/search it gives me 404 error it's normal or i need some configuration ?

Comment: I cannot say for sure, since I do not generally do what you are attempting, but you may need to do a build where you set the base-href at build-time using the `--base-href` option. See all build options [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build). Again, good luck! :)

Comment: okey, thank you so much Richard you are the Man